# How to DIY inside corners for radius bull nose tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, ceramic-tile

I'm wondering if anybody knows what is the best way (and any links online I may have missed) on how to do your own inside corners for radius bullnose tiles.  I have two situations for which I need to find a solution. The solution that the previous owner had was to just smear a bunch of caulk into the corners.

NOTE: I am replacing only the bull nose tiles, not the whole wall.

Situation 1:
[image]

Situation 2:
[image]

How the wall looks without the bullnose on it:
[image]

Any and all helps/tips are appreciated.  I just can't find any inside corner pieces for sale, anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't your product offer corner tiles? Most do nowdays.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: To be honest, I would look for a different edge tile instead of that bullnose, one that has a ready made inside corner piece available.

Comment: Does the inside corner piece have to match the bullnose?  Maybe you can find a decorative inside corner that you can use to hide the gap between the two end bullnose tiles.  May have to go to an upscale tile store for this.  But you only need one or two (one for each corner).

Comment: @SteveSh I always like "make it a feature" answers

Comment: The "situation 2" picture looks correct _except_ that it seems that the bullnose are different sizes. The vertical bullnose lines up just fine with the inside corner piece, but the horizontal one doesn't. Otherwise, that's _exactly_ how it should be done.

Comment: @FreeMan - I think it's just the lighting, shading, and camera angle that makes 'em look like they're different sizes.

Comment: The fact that they don't line up is what makes me think they're different sizes, @SteveSh...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I freehand mitered bullnose tile with a dry diamond blade in a grinder, which was what I had used for all the other tile cuts on that project (after being miserably disappointed with "tile nippers"), so I was pretty comfortable with it by the point I was doing the bullnose. *Dust mask, safety goggles, ear protection, work outside if at all possible for dust reasons...*

A tile saw might be less prone to error with little practice. Depending where you are getting your tile, the shop might cut a few on their saw for little or no cost as a service to a customer.

It wasn't terrible (either to do, or in looks.) You'll need enough extra bullnose to deal with the losses in making the miter cuts, and any losses in learning to make the mitre cuts. "Situation 1" only takes a little off each half of the corner, and runs a grout line into the corner of the wall.

"Situation 2" eats a great deal more, and will have a diagonal grout line right across the area where that small square corner tile is now. Without the "properly shaped corner piece" I think the diagonal grout line is a cleaner result than trying to cope-cut the mating tile to avoid it.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the procedure you are imagining for coping Situation 2 (which you did not recommend)? Cutting a trapezoidal relief from the bottom tile and just coping (grinding?) under the 45?

Comment: This requires DYI level 10

Answer (score 8):

The inside corners have to be mitered (ends cut @45 deg.) on a tile saw that has a tilting table. The flat corner is pretty much what you get with bullnose. A tile file and good eye can round one tile to conform to the edge of the other to make the joint cleaner.  Good Luck

Comment: that would work, assuming the corner is 90 deg

Comment: @Ruskes Tile saws can be adjusted to any angle

Comment: @RedSonja interesting, I have to yet see one that goes over 45 dgr.

Comment: @Ruskes cut from the other side _et voila!_ you have "more than" 45°. Or use a "manual" sliding tile cutter and you can hold the tile at any angle to the blade you choose.